# Google map return null in the Geocoding Results

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm try to get map by address, I did:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(self.$()[ 0 ], mapOptions);
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': self.get('address')}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        } else {
            console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }

});
```

I just copied the code from the google documention to test it,
So cause its dosen't display the map I start to debug it
I did `console.log` to the address and its fine.
I did `console.log` to the results object, and I get 3 results,  but each one of them have location have function with null values

I dont know what the problem , if someone can direct me what I dod wrong please

But I get the viewport, this optional to get google map by viewport?

**EDIT**
sorry, I just forget to give width & height to the map element

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't correctly pass the *div* element with the statment **self.$()[ 0 ]**, when you create the Map object:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(self.$()[ 0 ], mapOptions);
```

I've tried your code passing directly a div object and it correctly works.
See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/number_phi/e3bs70ku/3/)